# Why doesn't this work from other Classes or subClasses?

Tags: cocoa

I am trying to get the bounds of system selected Text, i found this Method here:

```
+ (void) getPosition{
    AXUIElementRef systemWideElement = AXUIElementCreateSystemWide();
    AXUIElementRef focussedElement = NULL;
    AXError error = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(systemWideElement, kAXFocusedUIElementAttribute, (CFTypeRef *)&focussedElement);

    if (error != kAXErrorSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"Could not get focussed element");
    } else {
        AXValueRef selectedRangeValue = NULL;
        AXError getSelectedRangeError = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(focussedElement, kAXSelectedTextRangeAttribute, (CFTypeRef *)&selectedRangeValue);
        if (getSelectedRangeError == kAXErrorSuccess) {
            CFRange selectedRange;
            AXValueGetValue(selectedRangeValue, kAXValueCFRangeType, &selectedRange);
            AXValueRef selectionBoundsValue = NULL;
            AXError getSelectionBoundsError = AXUIElementCopyParameterizedAttributeValue(focussedElement, kAXBoundsForRangeParameterizedAttribute, selectedRangeValue, (CFTypeRef *)&selectionBoundsValue);
            CFRelease(selectedRangeValue);
            if (getSelectionBoundsError == kAXErrorSuccess) {
                CGRect selectionBounds;
                AXValueGetValue(selectionBoundsValue, kAXValueCGRectType, &selectionBounds);
                NSLog(@"Selection bounds: %@", NSStringFromRect(NSRectFromCGRect(selectionBounds)));
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Could not get bounds for selected range");
            }
            if (selectionBoundsValue != NULL) CFRelease(selectionBoundsValue);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Could not get selected range");
        }
    }
    if (focussedElement != NULL) CFRelease(focussedElement);
    CFRelease(systemWideElement);
}
```

But if i call if from anything else than the appDelegate.m Class, it always returns:

```
Could not get focussed element
```

What have i missed to setup?

Or does anyone else knows hoow to get system selected Text Position?

Comment: I tried your answer, with no luck, i wanted to check error type, but it reruns a negative number like -2356 e.g.

Comment: Than i tried to check what the other variables have, but they are all empty, no info for any of them if i check any variable in here:AXUIElementRef systemWideElement = AXUIElementCreateSystemWide();
    AXUIElementRef focussedElement = NULL;
    AXError error = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(systemWideElement, kAXFocusedUIElementAttribute, (CFTypeRef *)&focussedElement);

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't initialize `focussedvalue` (actually spelled `focusedvalue`) as a `AXUIElementRef`, then typecast it when you pass it as an argument to `AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue`.
Instead, initialize it as a `CFTypeRef`.

Try that out, and see sample code here for reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/UIElementInspector/Listings/UIElementUtilities_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000728-UIElementUtilities_m-DontLinkElementID_14

Comment: Thx for the Answer, but i am a Beginner, its hard for me to follow your Steps while even "Initialize first2 is a Book with seven Seals for me ^^, can you give me a small hint or example where and how to init?

Comment: I overlooked my Code, sorry cannot follow your suggestion, for me, the code breaks away much earlier than any focusdValue gets initialized...

Comment: That's okay!  I'm sort of a beginner myself :)

'AXUIElementRef focussedElement = NULL;' is where you initialize the variable, and it should be of type 'CFTypeRef'

If you are getting 'could not focused element' then that means you are not breaking earlier and you are making it through to the point where you catch the error.  You could try checking the type of the error to get more information?

Comment: I tried your answer, with no luck, i wanted to check error type, but it reruns a negative number like -2356 e.g. –  Serge Sander 47 secs ago   edit   
      
Than i tried to check what the other variables have, but they are all empty, no info for any of them if i check any variable in here:AXUIElementRef systemWideElement = AXUIElementCreateSystemWide(); AXUIElementRef focussedElement = NULL; AXError error = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(systemWideElement, kAXFocusedUIElementAttribute, (CFTypeRef *)&focussedElement);

Comment: Yeah the errors are returned as constants (note the k prefix)
Here is a list of the errors and what they map to:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ApplicationServices/Reference/AXError_header_reference/Reference/reference.html

could you post which error you have?

Comment: Whatever this means:
 kAXErrorNoValue = -25212,
   /*! The parameterized attribute is not supported by the AXUIElementRef.

Comment: I tried back and forth, several times, even tried to use another Code just to get the focused Window only but it all fails, so no, i cannot post any updated Code, take the Code from init Post and try yourself from a second Window Controller Class like i do, from App Delaegate .m it works fine, from my other Class "CoreCode.m" it returns always the 25212 error Code

Answer (score 0):

So i found a way to position the window from my App Delegate.m File, so my thought was, if i cannot get the Bounds into my Custom Class, i take them from my AppDelegate.m File and position the Window inside there, well, nice thought, BUT, no matter what i do, i receive the 2Could not get Selection Range" Error Message, the Code is once again -25212, this whole stuff sucks a lot...

One of the creepiest Parts i had to deal as far in Cocoa...